# Rust pest parser fail

Tags: parsing, rust, peg, pest

I'm learning [pest parser](https://docs.rs/pest/latest/pest/) written in Rust and I need to parse a file:

```
{ISomething as Something, IOther as Other}
```

I wrote a rule:

```
LBrace = { "{" }
RBrace = { "}" }
Comma = { "," }
As = { "as" }
symbolAliases = { LBrace ~ importAliases ~ ( Comma ~ importAliases )* ~ RBrace }
importAliases = { Identifier ~ (As ~ Identifier)? }
Identifier = { IdentifierStart ~ IdentifierPart* }
IdentifierStart = _{ 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | "$" | "_" }
IdentifierPart = _{ 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | "$" | "_" }
```

But the parser throws an error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'unsuccessful parse: Error { variant: ParsingError { positives: [As, RBrace, Comma], negatives: [] }, location: Pos(11), line_col: Pos((1, 12)), path: None, line: "{ISomething as Something, IOther as Other}", continued_line: None }', src\main.rs:18:10
stack backtrace:
```

Help me figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not parsing any whitespace, that's your problem. It's expecting something like `{ISomethingasSomething,IOtherasOther}`. You can add a whitespace rule and add it in sensible places:

```
LBrace = { "{" }
RBrace = { "}" }
Comma = { "," }
As = { ws+ ~ "as" ~ ws+ }
//     ^^^^^------^^^^^
// an "as" token should probably be surrounded by whitespace to make sense

symbolAliases = { LBrace ~ importAliases ~ ( Comma ~ importAliases )* ~ RBrace }
importAliases = { ws* ~ Identifier ~ (As ~ Identifier)? }
//                ^^^^^

Identifier = { IdentifierStart ~ IdentifierPart* }
IdentifierStart = _{ 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | "$" | "_" }
IdentifierPart = _{ 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | "$" | "_" }

// whitespace rule defined here (probably want to add tabs and so on, too):
ws = _{ " " }
```

That's the least amount to make it parse, but you'll probably want it around braces and add some more fine-grained rules.

OR: you can [add them implicitly](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#implicit-whitespace), depending on your needs.

Comment: I don't quite understand if a pattern nested within another doesn't pest inserting ws by default?

Comment: @PFAhard Nope, it doesn't. Unless you [add them implicitly](https://pest.rs/book/grammars/syntax.html#implicit-whitespace).